# How to provide credentials for CassandraSink in PyFlink

Tags: python, cassandra, apache-flink, scylla, pyflink

please tell me, maybe someone has encountered this.

I need to configure CassandraSink in PyFlink in order to write aggregated data to a Cassandra/Skylla table on a stream. I couldn’t find either in the documentation or in the source code how to pass credentials to CassandraSink when setting it up

My current code

```py
cassandra_sink = CassandraSink \
        .add_sink(aggregated_stream) \
        .set_query(insert_query) \
        .set_host(CASSANDRA_HOST, int(CASSANDRA_PORT)) \
        .enable_ignore_null_fields() \
        .build()

cassandra_sink.set_parallelism(GLOBAL_PARALLELISM)
env.execute("Data Ingestion Job to Cassandra")
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd need a cluster builder object to pass in credentials and other sophisticated configs for your c* sink passed via the [`setClusterBuilder`](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/connectors/datastream/cassandra/#configurations).

```
ClusterBuilder clusterBuilder = new ClusterBuilder() {    
    @Override    
    protected Cluster buildCluster(Cluster.Builder builder) {      
        return builder.addContactPointsWithPorts(new InetSocketAddress(HOST,PORT))
                      .withQueryOptions(new QueryOptions().setConsistencyLevel(CL))                    
                      .withSocketOptions(new SocketOptions()                   
                      .setConnectTimeoutMillis(CONNECT_TIMEOUT)                    
                      .setReadTimeoutMillis(READ_TIMEOUT)) 
                      .withCredentials(username, password)                   
                      .build();    
    }
};
```

and then provide it to the sink as follows:

```
cassandra_sink = CassandraSink \
    .setClusterBuilder(builder)
    // .set your other configurations such as queries, etc.
    .build()
    .name("Cassandra Sink");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! For a Java implementation this works fine, but I'm trying to use Pyflink ClusterBuilder :(

And here the class does not have any configuration methods -


class ClusterBuilder(object):
    def __init__(self, j_cluster_builder):
        self._j_cluster_builder = j_cluster_builder